# TouchableWithoutFeedBack not responding when ListView is wrapped in

Tags: listview, react-native, react-native-listview

I want to detect when a user release touch on a ListView in order to be able to center my cells at that moment. In iOS I’ve wrapped my ListView in a TouchableWithoutFeedBack and it’s working fine. The `onPress` is called when the user stops touching it. But in Android, `onPress` is not called.

I can’t put all my ListViews rows in Touchables because the user won’t be able to touch it and continue scrolling.

Here’s my code :

```
render() {
   return (
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => this.release()}>
            <ListView
             ref="dateStripe"
             bounces={true}
             style={{paddingRight: (ScreenWidth / 2) - (ScreenWidth / 5 / 2), paddingLeft: (ScreenWidth / 2) - (ScreenWidth / 5 / 2)}}
             scrollEventThrottle={1}
             horizontal={true}
             onScroll={this.onScroll}
             showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
             dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
             renderRow={this._renderItem.bind(this)}
           />
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    )
}
```